# Automation on SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I would like to ask a question for connoisseurs of SQL (MySQL, to be specific).

I have a table reservation schedules. And when a customer makes a reservation there is a time to let the client to use my service. Therefore, the reservation that he did have to leave the table reservations.

> Once the time limit of use is reached, there is some method (trigger,
>   I believe), which automatically erase the record of this book on the
>   table?

If so, can someone give me some idea of ​​how to start my search for it, or it is also totally welcome some help as some more advanced lines of code.

There is also the possibility that this only be possible to be implemented via Server-Side (PHP, ASP ...), which does not believe is so true because SQL is a language very complete (to my knowledge).

Edit1: The problem is that I believe this is a task of the DBMS, so I wanted to leave this responsibility to the MySQL The problem is: how?

Comment: You could use a cronjob that searches through the records and deletes the appropriate ones, using whatever language you like

Answer (score 2):

A `trigger` is triggered by either before or after an `insert` , `update` or `delete` event (at least in MySQL according to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html))

What you want is some sort of scheduled job either through your application be it php, asp.net, etc.. or cron job that calls some sort of SQL script.

So to answer, it can't be done purely with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more column in your table where you will create the expiration date. Then you can on your sql server create the job that will erase all records that have expiration date less than curent date.

```
   CREATE EVENT db_name 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
   DO
   DELETE FROM myschema.mytable WHERE expiration_date < NOW()
```

I hope that will help.

Comment: That, I know. The problem is that I believe this is a task of the DBMS, so I wanted to leave this responsibility to the MySQL The problem is: how?

Comment: You can try with this code: CREATE EVENT db_name
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 10 SECOND
    DO
DELETE FROM myschema.mytable WHERE expiration_date < NOW()

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL jobs, but if the removal logic is to complex to manage it with queries I suggest you to use a PHP script that does all that work for you.
Just write down the data check/remove logic in PHP and set up a simple cron operation for it.

The advantage of this solution is that you can access to your scripts/classes/db providers and save your time and your can log all the operations separately (instead of logging to MySQL logs, no matter what script language you are relying on).

If you have a full control of your server the scheduled operation will look like this (if you want to check your DB entries every day at 00:01):

```
cat /etc/cron.d/php5
0 1 * * * php /path/to/your/script.php >> /path/to/your_script.log
```

..otherwise you will have to check the control panel of your hosting account and figure out how to manage